# What is the reason for the rapid flashing of the green lamp on the Nikon COOLPIX S2900 camera when charging?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, camera

I have a Nikon COOLPIX S2900.  Since yesterday when I try to charge it, the green light on the camera is blinking fast whereas before, it was blinking slowly when charging. This rapid flashing continues for a few seconds and then the lamp turns off completely and the camera does not charge. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you replace the battery since you get the camera?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Nope.

Comment: There is a great chance your battery is out, need to be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera's [manual](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/bnr8d00jcoO701S6xHz82HmhJl48/S2900RM_(En)02.pdf) says this:

- The charge lamp slowly flashes green to indicate that the battery is charging.
- When charging is complete, the charge lamp turns off. It takes about 3 hours
  to charge a fully exhausted battery.
- The battery cannot be charged when the charge lamp quickly flashes green,
  possibly due to one of the reasons described below.

  - The ambient temperature is not suited to charging.
  - The USB cable or Charging AC Adapter is not properly connected.
  - The battery is damaged.